# Host multiple sites on one domain with IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have few web apps: ASP.NET MVC 4.5, ASP.NET CORE MVC 3/6 and also blazor wasm hosted on ASP.NET CORE 6.
I want to hosst them on one domain with different paths as roots. Like this:

```
mydomain.com/firstsite
mydomain.com/secondsite
mydomain.com/thirdsite
```

and etc.
Can I do it somehow on Windows Server 2016 with IIS? Every site use his own authenticication and cookies.

Comment: Create one parent site, then host other sites under the parent as applications. I suggest you go try that out.

Comment: Those are not called sites on IIS but applications, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis and what you described is well supported for decades. The question is what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can achieve this requirement, we can add virtual application under IIS site.

[image]

## Mytest Steps

**1. Setings in IIS**

[image]

**2. Important point, please note.**

If we set the main site to .net framework, then the virtual application .net core site should recreate an application pool.

Because the application pool of .net core should choose `No Manage Code` type.

**3. In your blazor webapp, you need change the default path like below.**

Add the virtual path in your index.html file.

[image]

Comment: Used a similiar way to yours which also worked, I will link the [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/358513/1025836) here if anybody else stumbles upon this.